# Problem in calculus of variation.

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Solve $$v(y_1,y_2)=\displaystyle \int_0^\pi(y_1'^2-y_2'^2)dx $$
$$ y_1(0)=y_2(0)=y_1(\pi)=0  , \ y_2(\pi)=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
$$ y_1'-y_2 +\cos(x)=0 $$.

After solving Euler-Lagrange equation for $F(x,y_1,y_2,y_1',y_2')=y_1'^2-y_2'^2 +\lambda( y_1'-y_2 +\cos(x))\  $ , I am getting 
$$ y_1=Ax+B \ ,\ y_2= \frac{\lambda}{4}x^2+Cx+D$$
But the  given answer is $y_1=\frac{x}{2}\sin(x) \ , y_2=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(x)-x\cos(x))$ which is clearly not the same to what I have got. Where am I wrong? Could you please help me?

Comment: It could be either a problem in your textbook or a problem in your posting, but $y_1(x) = \frac{1}{2}x\sin x$, $y_2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin x - x\cos x)$ is **not** a solution to the problem. You can check that by calculating the constraint, it should be zero, but instead you get $y_1'(x) - y_2(x) + \cos x = (1 + x)\cos x$

Answer (score 0):

In this type of problem, the parameter $\lambda$ must be a function of $x$. This is so, because $y_1'$ is involved in the constraint equation.

The augmented Lagrangian is then 
$$\mathcal{L}=\tfrac{1}{2}(y_1'^2-y_2'^2) + \tfrac{\lambda}{2}(y'_1-y_2+\cos{x})$$

Now, due to the fact that the integral 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathcal{L}\,dx$$
must be an extremum along the path
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y'_i}\right)-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial y_i}=0\qquad i=1,2$$
subjected to the contraint 
$$y'_1-y_2 +\cos{x}=0$$

Leads to the following  system of linear differential equations
$$\begin{align}
y_1''+\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda'&=0\tag1\\
y_2''-\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda&=0\tag2\\
y'_1-y_2+\cos{x}&=0 \tag3
\end{align}$$ 
From $(1)$
$$y_1'=c_1-\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda\tag4$$
from the latter equation and $(2)$
$$y_2=\cos{x}+\tfrac{1}{2}(c_1-\lambda)\tag5$$
and $(3)$ turns to 
$$\lambda''+\lambda+\cos{x}=0\tag6$$

Solve first for $\lambda$ in $(6)$, and substitute it in $(4)$ and $(5)$ to obtain $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Finally solve the linear system for the constants $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ and $c_4$ with the given extremal values on $x=0$ and $x=\pi$.

Hope I have not committed any mistake.

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{2}$ in $\mathcal{L}?$

Comment: If you multiply the Lagrangian by any number, you will obtain the same equations of motion. It is only a fact of beauty. Do not care about the $1/2$ and follow the procedure with your Lagrangian, it will lead to the same equations as mine.